# servlet xpages init() method

Tags: servlets, xpages

I implemented 2 servlets following

http://xpages-learn.appspot.com/viewstory/4001?q=117630849870799440326
http://8b30b0.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/creating-a-basic-domino-servlet/#comments

and having a look at life cycle diagram
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-CYv9tvbnENk/ThiKfA6o5vI/AAAAAAAAABo/w-SxMG4Y33s/s1600/Servlet+life+cycle+1.JPG

and servlets life cycle
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-life-cycle.htm

As I understand init() method is called in constructor = once. With over-ridding init() method like

`public void init() {testString += " " + this.hashCode();}`

defining global variable

`public static String testString = "";`

defining servlet response to return testString and then sending 2 requests to servlet. I expect getting only one hashCode(). The one of servlet instance.

Problem is in response. In both tutorials testString grows and returns 2 different hashes (one for each request). Why?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for any class in Java is the name of of the class, not an arbitrary function. The init function is called by the JEE container and could be called, depending on the container more than one. There's [an interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) for that.

Good practise: in init() initialize stuff if not there already.